# Weird mark questions between Class members

Tags: jsf

I have a separate module project setup to load from jar(this is working as expected) but when  I try to load a List of objects in datatable or h:selectOneMenu then Class member are shown instead values i.e

```
 public class Client implements Serializable {
 private BigInteger idclient;
 private String name;
  public BigInteger getIdclient() {
        return this.idclient;
    }

    public void setIdclient(BigInteger idclient) {
        this.idclient = idclient;
    }

 public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

in controller i have List listClient;

```
<h:selectOneMenu styleClass="select-input"
                                id="registerzoneClient" 
                                valueChangeListener="#{managerZoneController.listCountries}"
                                onchange="this.form.submit();">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Client" itemValue="-1" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{managerZoneController.listClients}"
                                    var="client" itemLabel="#{client.name}"
                                    itemValue="#{client.idclient}" itemDescription="#{client.name}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

selectOneMenu label is ???name??? and value is ???idclient???

Comment: maybe some code of yours puts that in there as a string?

Comment: same code works if  managed bean is into  project, but now managed bean is in a different project exported and loaded in jar file.